# Resteasy - Getting 500 error on Post operation

Tags: java-8, resteasy

I am new using REST-EASY and I am stuck on an issue.
I get a 500 error when performing a POST operation.

Here is a sample of my project below:

**pom.xml**

```
...
<properties>
        <resteasy.version>3.6.3.Final</resteasy.version>
        <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- resteasy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--rest-easy client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- unit test:::needed by reast-easy-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

**web.xml**

```
<!-- Auto scan rest service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/spy</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
     
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/spy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**TestController.java**

```
@Path("/pay")
public class TestController {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String testME(Message message) throws Exception {
        return "IT WOX;
    }
}
```

**Message.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    private Boolean flag;
    private String text;
}
```

**ServeMeApplication**

```
public class HandlerApplication extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<>();

    public HandlerApplication() {
        singletons.add(new TestController());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

**I use POSTMAN to hit this service and a 500 is thrown back with the following error snippet**

```
throws java.lang.Exception  ( org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class handler.tier.payload.Message of content type: application/json )
```

**When I add resteasy-jackson provider in my pom, I get a 404**

**Please help! I have been trying different sources and I am stuck.**

Comment: That is a very old version of RESTEasy. You’re also mixing two different versions. What container are you running in?

Comment: I am running it on tomcat

Comment: At least use the same version if RESTEasy. I would suggest using a newer version as well.